# Ie 7 float bug how to have stuff on same line

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

Hi to all I'm trying to create a website for my brother http://labelenne.com but I have a compatibility issue with IE7 (I want the template to be compatible from Ie7 to Ie9+)

As usual no problem with serious browsers but with ie7... As you can see on homepage I have a few posts what I would like to achieve is to have them floating like they do in Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Final result will have 3 posts for each category on same line maybe actually also in chrome only 2 of them are on a single line... I don't care I know webkit so I also know how to solve this, simply in Italy is 2:20Am so I need to sleep!

Is there anyone who can tell me what is the problem with IE7? Thank you very much and good night!

Comment: Please show us the code snippets in question so we can see what you have.

Comment: Have you seen this on larger screens?

Comment: http://i44.tinypic.com/w9fc7p.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to experiment with your code with ie7, I can't know for sure, but I have a hunch it has to do with having % based widths on the divs.  Have you tried setting px widths instead?

Comment: yes it was a % issue and a media query issue 'cause I forgot that IE7 has problems with media query.